# How to implement array of struct under struct ? i got this "UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct to storage not yet supported."

Tags: compiler-errors, blockchain, solidity

I want to access voteGiven array under Election struct it is showing me UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Voting.VoteGiven memory[] memory to storage not yet supported error

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.22;

contract Voting {
   

    struct VoteGiven {
        address voter;
        string optionChosen;
    }

    struct Election {
        string electionName;
        string[] options;
        VoteGiven[] voterIndexes; // Store the indexes of voters in the voters array
    }

    mapping(address => Election[]) private electionsWithAddress;
    VoteGiven[] public allVotes; // Store all votes in a single array

    function createElection(string memory electionName, string[] memory options, address creator) public {
        require(bytes(electionName).length > 0, "Election name must be provided");
        require(options.length > 0, "Options must be provided");
        require(creator != address(0), "Creator address must be provided");

        Election memory newElection;
        newElection.electionName = electionName;
        newElection.options = options;

        electionsWithAddress[creator].push(newElection);

       
    }

    function vote(address creator, string memory electionName, string memory optionChosen) public {
        uint256 electionIndex = findElectionIndex(creator, electionName);
        require(electionIndex != type(uint256).max, "Election not found");

        VoteGiven memory newVote;
        newVote.voter = msg.sender;
        newVote.optionChosen = optionChosen;

        allVotes.push(newVote);
        electionsWithAddress[creator][electionIndex].voterIndexes.push(newVote);
    }


    //find specific 
    function findElectionIndex(address creator, string memory electionName) internal view returns (uint256) {
        Election[] storage elections = electionsWithAddress[creator];
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < elections.length; i++) {
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(elections[i].electionName)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(electionName))) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return type(uint256).max; // Not found
    }

    function getElection (address _address,uint256 index) public  view returns (Election memory){
       Election memory election= electionsWithAddress[_address][index];
       return election;
    }
    function getAllVoteOfElection(address creator,string memory electionName) public view {
        uint256 electionIndex = findElectionIndex(creator, electionName);
        require(electionIndex != type(uint256).max, "Election not found");
    }
}
```

I did many things if we remove this voteGiven form struct and used other array then no problem we face